# Rails make a model require another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, model, database-relations

If I have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship between two models, let's say `Users` and `Accounts`, can I require that a `User` have at least one `Account`, and how?

Also, using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship, is it possible for an `Account` not to have a `User`?

What I need is a relationship where `Accounts` can live on their own, and belong to `Billers`, but they can also belong to `Users` if a `User` signed up with one. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would drop the the HABTM.  Instead I would use `has_many :though=>`

You would need to create two new models, account_users, and account_billers.  You likely already have join tables for the HABTM, but this will expose them as models so they will need ID fields.

So you would end up with something like the following:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_billers
  has_many :account_users

  has_many :billers, :through=> :account_billers
  has_many :users, :through=> :account_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_users
  has_many :accounts, :through=>:account_users

  validates :accounts, :length => { :minimum => 1}
end

class Biller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_billers
  has_many :accounts, :through=>:account_billers

  validates :accounts, :length => { :minimum => 1}
end

class AccountUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end

class AccountBiller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :biller
  belongs_to :account
end
```

Comment: This would setup a requirement that users and billers have accounts, but accounts could exist with out having a user or a biller.

Answer (score 0):

To validate presence of at least one association, you might want to use a [custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods), something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :accounts
  validate :require_at_least_one_account

  private
    def require_at_least_one_account
      errors.add(:accounts, "must amount to at least one") if accounts.size < 1
    end
end
```

(Although this brings a question of how an account is shared between users)

For your second question, looks like [polymorphic associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) are what you're looking for, but you can't do this straight with a HABTM relationship, you'll have to change it to a `has_many :through` and introduce a join model.

Comment: You could use polymorphic, but there is no good way to do FK constraints with polymorphism. If user1521444 doesn't have a great grasp of the models and relations yet, I would avoid this.

Comment: With polymorphic associations it seems as if you can then have an account belong to either a User or Biller, but can the same account belong to both under a polymorphic association?

Comment: If you can have accounts belonging to both users and billers at the same time, I don't think AR supports this out of the box. You can check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209322/rails-polymorphic-has-many